# Excel - Easily insert new data row in a table with total row

Tags: microsoft-excel

The following is an easy and very useful way to insert a new data row in a table.

...BUT it seems not to be working when your table has a "total" row.

Any workaround?

> Start typing in the cell below the table’s last row to add a new row

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daHzZ.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZJIx.png)

Comment: right click, inset row

Comment: Drag the blue table "handle" at the bottom right down to include more rows? You can even do this *after* you type more data below the total row and it will include it in the table then move the total down below it, "swapping" the data and total effectively.

Comment: for those that like keyboard shortcuts https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-shortcut-to-insert-a-row-in-excel-b7dd8f7f-2fce-58d3-cf6c-37443846264c